# что означает => при создании объекта?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

Имеется код:

```
namespace HelloApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Что означает "=>" ? Что IWebHostBuilder создаётся при помощи вызова метода WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup(); ?

Comment: `=>` читайте как `это есть` или `c этим следует сделать`. `IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(…)` `это есть` `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()`

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не совсем дубликат, там про свойство, здесь про метод

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае это - [член, воплощающий выражение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). Т.е. индексатор/свойство/конструктор/метод суть которых состоит всего в одной цепочки действий, грубо говоря метода в одну строку.

Так же в других случаях это является ["оператором =>"](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-operator) отделяющим параметры лямбда-выражения от его тела.

Грубо говоря, конкретно ваша строка означает "Когда будет вызван этот метод выполнить вот это выражение и вернуть его результат". Такое выражение не обязательно возвращает результат. Например можно сделать вот так:

```
string Default => "Хехе";

void Do(string value) => Console.WriteLine(value);

public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Do(Default); //Так вы покажете в консоли "Хехе"
}
```